# finished, have finished, be finished, be done, ,have done, did,

Tags: verbs

I'd like to know the exact difference of those.

I finished my homework.

I am finished with my homework.

I have finished my homework.

I did my homework.

I am done with my homework.

I have done my homework.

Do they have different meanings?
You might say those are slitely the same, but what if the objects are replaced with other things.

Answer (score 2):

> I finished my homework.

This sentence uses past simple. Your homework was completed in the past.

> I am finished with my homework.

In this sentence, *finished* is an adjective. Just like the word "done", it means that you are not requiring any work at it.

> I have finished my homework.

This is present perfect tense. 
Your work is completed. But the consequence probably exists in presence as the current state. For more information, please read [The Pragmatic Meaning of the Perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32)

Finished and Done are interchangeable here, there is no significant difference. But sometimes, *done* can be meant to be tired. For example, *I'm done with your excuses* means *I'm tired with your excuses*.

Comment: "done", in my opinion, tends to be a more american usage in this scenario (I wouldn't use it so much in Britain, anyway)

Answer (score 1):

The first three mean the same thing.

"I did my homework" means only that you have worked on your homework, but maybe not completed (finished) it. Maybe you still have some left.

Note however that when most people say "I did my homework" they will often mean that they finished it.

"I am done with my homework" means that you have had enough of doing your homework and will not continue doing it at this moment. Again, it doesn't necessarily mean you finished all your homework, although it is more finalising that "I did my homework."

"I have done my homework" means, like the first three, that you have finished it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, while here below we are discussing “those”, you were above asking about “these”. Does that make sense?

Either way the examples do have broadly similar meanings but there are significant differences, including these below:

I finished my homework.
I completed my homework at some time in the past. I might have started the work previously and set it aside, but during the session in question, I completed the work.

I am finished with my homework.
I completed whatever homework I had and I do not expect any more; not in the immediate future and not impossibly, never.

I have finished my homework.
I have just now completed my homework, seconds or at most minutes ago.

I did my homework.
Very much the same as “I finished my homework.”
Some might say "did" could as easily mean "finished" or simply "worked on".
Some might say “finished” could indicate a session resumed and “did”, completion in a single session.

I am done with my homework.
Not just similar; probably identical to “I am finished with my homework.

I have done my homework.
Very much the same as “I have finished my homework” but rather less immediate. “Done” is more likely than “finished” to imply “I did it yesterday”.

Further, “I am done / finished with my (anything)” are anchored within the same range of meaning only by that possessive “my”.

With the possessive “my” the sentence is a specific, factual report about the fate of a concrete and measurable thing.

Without the possessive “my” it would become instead a generic philosophical statement of intent about an abstract and unmeasurable subject.